# Move CoreData content from light to full version

Tags: ios, core-data, export

I need to move CoreData content from light version of the app to full version of the app, Is it any way how to do that?

Comment: you mean like versioning your core-data db?

Comment: I mean export all CoreData content from Light version of the app to Full version of the app.

Comment: so that means you have 2 separate apps? if thats the case I dont think you can transfer data from one to another. I think uploading data to a server from the lite version and then downloading it from the full version might be a solution.

Comment: Maybe using custom URL schemes? Send sql base file from light version to full version.

Comment: well to be honest im not sure about that coz i haven't used custom URL schemes before :( sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it via iCloud. Enable iCloud with a single instance for both apps, update your light app to enable the upload, and download into full app via iCloud.

Good luck!

Check out [Using Core Data with iCloud](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/DataManagement/RN-iCloudCoreData/), as well as the section [Designing for Core Data in iCloud](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/iCloudDesignGuide/Chapters/DesignForCoreDataIniCloud.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012094-CH3-SW1) in the iCloud Design Guide. The second one has pointers to all the APIs you need.